# Finding possible key combination of a char regarding current keyboard layout

Tags: c#, c++, keyboard

How can I find a possible key combination of a char regarding to current keyboard layout

for example;

lets say my keyboard's caps lock is off
So in that case for char "A" key combination should be Shift + A

that was easy. how about non ascii chars or non visible chars on keyboard such as "@" char or "\"

```
for "@" I use Ctrl + Alt + Q
for "\" I use Ctrl + Alt + *
for "{" I use Ctrl + Alt + 7
```

So how could I know which key combination should I send to an application to make it handle "{" key assuming that application validates that combination to determine if I am bot or human.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The C++ standard library does not have functionality for raw keyboard handling. I don't think you will find any portable library for it either. So you're essentially stuck with OS API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows you can use `VkKeyScan(char ch)` function. It returns a short value which contains the virtual key code on low-order byte and modifier key flags on high-order byte.

You can call it in C# by declaring:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern short VkKeyScan(char ch);
```

Here is the link to the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I think that can cover my requirements. Except the current virtual key code. So If I want to send '#' character over api VkKeyScan will return me Alt + Ctrl, but not Key.D3 . So How could I extract the Key.D3 then ?

Comment: You can mask the return value: `int virtualKeyCode = returnValue & 0xFF` to get the key.

Comment: GREAT. that works. except it says 'Shift' + 65 for  'A'  if caps lock is on. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You must check the state of CapsLock key yourself. Fortunately you can use `GetKeyState(int nVirtKey)` function to get it.